# How I fix RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Tags: flutter

I'm creating an interface from an api data everything works fine, but when I add a value to my list of TextEditingController the error of "RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1" appear and I do not know why Is happening this if you could help me I'll be grateful

this is my code.

```
List<TextEditingController> openQuest = List<TextEditingController>();

Widget _questions(){
return FutureBuilder(
  future: widget.questSect,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      return Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            if(snapshot.data[index]['tipo_pregunta'] == 2){
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height:5),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .88,
                      child: Text(
                        snapshot.data[index]['pregunta'],
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: SECONDARY_TEXT,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        )
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }else{
              openQuest.add(TextEditingController());
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(height:5),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .88,
                      child: Text(
                        snapshot.data[index]['pregunta'],
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: SECONDARY_TEXT,
                          fontSize: 16,
                        )
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                    InputCustom(
                      cont: openQuest.length < 0 ? TextEditingController() : openQuest[index],
                      icono: null,
                      labelText: null,
                      validate: (String val){
                        if(val.isEmpty){
                          return 'Se debe contestar la pregunta';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      max: 100,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
            
          },
        ),
      );
    }else if(snapshot.hasError){
      return Center(
        child: Text('Error al traer las preguntas.'),
      );
    }

    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
            child: Text('Obteniendo preguntas...'),
          )
        ]
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look I think the problem lies in this line

```
cont: openQuest.length < 0 ? TextEditingController() : openQuest[index],
```

You have created the `openQuest` and only adding one item to the list. But as of your condition

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
            if(snapshot.data[index]['tipo_pregunta'] == 2){
```

any `value` other than 2 the `index` is passed on to the else part which can be greater than the length of `openQuest` and your  `openquest` list only has one element... try changing that to something like `openQuest[openQuest.length - 1]`

Comment: when I wrote the line of cont:openQuest.length < 0 bla bla I was trying other options I forgot to modify it when I asked, thanks for the correction, and you were right I changed to openQuest[index-1] and it works, thank you so much!!